# Python "listdir" vs command line "dir" or "ls"

Tags: python, directory, listdir

On a networked drive with a large set of data, I need to find a set of directories relevant to a project I am working on.  The data of interest are located in a generic path "dir\subdir\subsubdir".  Within a given subdir the list of directories is long and unknown, so to iterate over them I planned to use python's `os.listdir('dir/subdir')` function.  There are three dir's to iterate over, within each are two subdir's (the names are the same for all three dir's).  My problem is that with the code:

```
import os
for tree in ['dir_a','dir_b','dir_c']:
  for branch in ['subdir_a','subdir_b']:
    filelist = os.listdir(tree+'/'+branch)
```

For ONE of the possible six dir-subdir pairs I get the error

```
WindowsError: [Error 1392] The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable: 'dir_c\\subdir_b\\*.*'
```

It is, however, possible to [1] view this path in file explorer, [2] use the listdir function successfully on dir_c\subdir_b\subsubdir_* for any directory within dir_c\subdir_b , and [3] get a list of directories in dir_c\subdir_b via listdir on the command line.

**Question:**  Why is python's os.listdir() telling me a directory is unreadable when it is possible via Windows to read the directory?

Comment: A better question is, why is Windows not telling you that a corrupted directory is corrupted? And the answer is, because Windows.

Comment: Are you running your python script from the networked directory? Python looks for `dir_a/subdir_a` in the current working directory. Therefore, you may need to specify a `F:\` to start with

Comment: @inspectorG4dget : I left out the less-important bits for readability; yes, I'm working on the correct drive letter, etc.  Like I said, the other 5 dir-subdir pairs operate exactly as I expect them to, and the operations on 'filelist' (not shown) produce the desired data.  Thanks for checking though!

Comment: I would recommend against using `tree + '/' + branch`.  There is no guarantee that `/` is the correct path delimiter.  You can use `os.path.join(tree, branch)`.